# convert unbound Gridview column values to lowercase at runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, linq-to-entities

I have an unbound Gridview that is populated by a Linq to Entities query and would like to convert string values in a particular column to lowercase.

In the Gridview's **RowDataBound** event, i have tried  `StrConv(e.Row.Cells(3).Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)` but this doesn't work.

I have also tried `StrConv(emp.Name, VbStrConv.ProperCase)` in the LiNQ to Entities query but still the Name values returned are to converted to Lower-case.

```
Protected Sub GridView3_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowDataBound
           If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
            Dim cellDate As Date
            If Date.TryParse(e.Row.Cells(i).Text, cellDate) Then
                e.Row.Cells(i).Text = String.Format("{0:d}", cellDate)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    StrConv(e.Row.Cells(4).Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, strConv returns a string, which should be used, I think like:

e.Row.Cells(4).Text = StrConv(e.Row.Cells(4).Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)

Comment: I have added the code. The following line of code is not working as expected i.e changing the values in Cell(4) to lowercase StrConv(e.Row.Cells(4).Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to do this:

> string strLower = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToLower();

and then use the strLower as the lower case string.

Comment: Tried that as well with out sucess